# Automated deploys JBoss/Tomcat

Tags: deployment, artifactory

i'm looking for a tool to make remote automatic deployments in JBoss/Tomcat(under linux/unix) where a component is updated and version is incremented in my Artifactory.

For example.

I have an instance called 'A' under tomcat/jboss with the deployed component "my-plugin-1.0.jar" . Then I upload the component "my-plugin-1.1.jar" in artifactory, and after that, i need the automatic update of this new component in my application server.

Does anyone know any tool that can do this?

Thanks in advance

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are into serious DevOps development, [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) or [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) are your tools.
If you don't feel like writing Ruby scripts, [ZeroTurnaround's LiveRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/liverebel/) is a way to go.